# EF Core many to many unwanted columns

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to create a model which has two time many to many relation.

> StockItem * - * QualityCheckDefinition
>
> Article *  -  * QualityCheckDefinition

Many to many classes:

```
public class StockItemQualityCheckDefinition
{
    public StockItem StockItem { get; set; }
    public QualityCheckDefinition QualityCheckDefinition { get; set; }

    public int StockItemId { get; set; }
    public int QualityCheckDefinitionId { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleQualityCheckDefinition
{
    public Article Article { get; set; }
    public QualityCheckDefinition QualityCheckDefinition { get; set; }

    public string ArticleId { get; set; }
    public int QualityCheckDefinitionId { get; set; }
}
```

QualityCheckDefinition class:

```
public class QualityCheckDefinition : Entity<int>
{
    public List<StockItemQualityCheckDefinition> StockItemQualityCheckDefinitions { get; set; }
    public List<ArticleQualityCheckDefinition> ArticleQualityCheckDefinitions { get; set; }         
}
```

Article class:

```
public class Article : Entity<string>
{
    public ICollection<ArticleQualityCheckDefinition> ArticleQualityCheckDefinitions { get; set; }
}
```

StockItem class:

```
public class StockItem : Entity<int>
{
    public List<StockItemQualityCheckDefinition> StockItemQualityCheckDefinitions { get; set; }
}
```

The mappings:

```
public class ArticleQualityCheckDefinitionMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ArticleQualityCheckDefinition>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ArticleQualityCheckDefinition> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => new { x.ArticleId, x.QualityCheckDefinitionId });

        builder.HasOne(x => x.Article)
               .WithMany(x => x.ArticleQualityCheckDefinitions)
               .HasForeignKey(x => x.ArticleId)
               .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.Id)
               .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        builder.HasOne(x => x.QualityCheckDefinition)
               .WithMany(x => x.ArticleQualityCheckDefinitions)
               .HasForeignKey(x => x.QualityCheckDefinitionId)
               .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.Id)
               .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }
}

public class StockItemQualityDefinitionMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<StockItemQualityCheckDefinition>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<StockItemQualityCheckDefinition> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => new { x.StockItemId, x.QualityCheckDefinitionId });

        builder.HasOne(x => x.StockItem)
               .WithMany(x => x.StockItemQualityCheckDefinitions)
               .HasForeignKey(x => x.StockItemId);

        builder.HasOne(x => x.QualityCheckDefinition)
               .WithMany(x => x.StockItemQualityCheckDefinitions)
               .HasForeignKey(x => x.QualityCheckDefinitionId);
    }
}
```

The relationships are configured fine and they are working. However migration creates additional unnesesary fields inside `QualityCheckDefinition` class. Migration wants to add both nullable `StockItemId` and `ArticleId` into `QualityCheckDefinition` class.

There is part of migration:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "QualityCheckDefinitions",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    //other properties
                    ArticleId = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    StockItemId = table.Column<int>(nullable: true)
                },
```

Why does it add these unwanted keys?

PS. I am using EF Core 2.2

Comment: Your configuration looks like it's EF configuration, not EF Core configuration. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships for more info

Comment: I see no difference in Many-Many section

Comment: Most likely your `Article` and `StockItem` classes contain "helper" properties like `public IEnumerable<QualityCheckDefinition> QualityCheckDefinitions` which are discovered as navigation properties.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your configuration mapping for `StockItem` and `Article`? And I think the way you used `.HasPrincipalKey()` inside `ArticleQualityCheckDefinitionMap` is not right.

#### Principal Key

> If you want the foreign key to reference a property other than the primary key, you can use the Fluent API to configure the principal key property for the relationship. The property that you configure as the principal key will automatically be setup as an alternate key.

#### Your `ArticleQualityCheckDefinitionMap`

```
builder.HasOne(x => x.Article)
    .WithMany(x => x.ArticleQualityCheckDefinitions)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.ArticleId)        // <--
    .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.Id)             // <--
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

By conventions, `.HasForeignKey(x => x.ArticleId)` will target the primary key of the `Article` entity, `string Id`. And then you told Entity Framework that you don't want to setup the foreign key to the primary key. You want to target another property called `Id` by saying `.HasPrincipalKey(x => x.Id)`.

Huh? Aren't they the same? That's why I think Entity Framework got confused. And since you **don't** have a configuration for `Article`, Entity Framework tried its best to generate a primary key for you, called "ArticleId"?

You can fix the problem by just adding the configurations back and removing `.HasPrincipalKey()` there.

#### StockItemConfiguration

```
using DL.SO.EFCore.Learning.Data.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

namespace DL.SO.EFCore.Learning.Data.Configurations
{
    public class StockItemConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<StockItem>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<StockItem> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

            builder.ToTable(nameof(StockItem));
        }
    }
}
```

#### ArticleConfiguration

```
using DL.SO.EFCore.Learning.Data.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

namespace DL.SO.EFCore.Learning.Data.Configurations
{
    public class ArticleConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Article>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Article> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

            builder.ToTable(nameof(Article));
        }
    }
}
```

You might need to configure for `QualityCheckDefinition` as well:

#### QualityCheckDefinitionConfiguration

```
using DL.SO.EFCore.Learning.Data.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

namespace DL.SO.EFCore.Learning.Data.Configurations
{
    public class QualityCheckDefinitionConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<QualityCheckDefinition>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<QualityCheckDefinition> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

            builder.ToTable(nameof(QualityCheckDefinition));
        }
    }
}
```

Then remove `.HasPrincipalKey()`:

#### ArticleQualityCheckDefinitionConfiguration

```
using DL.SO.EFCore.Learning.Data.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

namespace DL.SO.EFCore.Learning.Data.Configurations
{
    public class ArticleQualityCheckDefinitionConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ArticleQualityCheckDefinition>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ArticleQualityCheckDefinition> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(x => new { x.ArticleId, x.QualityCheckDefinitionId });

            builder.HasOne(x => x.Article)
                .WithMany(x => x.ArticleQualityCheckDefinitions)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.ArticleId);

            builder.HasOne(x => x.QualityCheckDefinition)
                .WithMany(x => x.ArticleQualityCheckDefinitions)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.QualityCheckDefinitionId);

            builder.ToTable(nameof(ArticleQualityCheckDefinition));
        }
    }
}
```

Then you should be fine?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for long answer. I refactored code with your recommendations into the code but still result is the same...

Comment: @miechooy: did you add configurations for `StockItem`, `Article` and `QualityCheckDefinition`?